# What is the equivalent ee.Image.not() in Python

Tags: javascript, python, refactoring, google-earth-engine

I'm using geemap package to refactor a code from JavaScript to Python and I couldn't find a way to replicate these two lines

```js
var swbdMask = swbd.unmask().not().focal_median(1)
var hmask = hand30_100.gt(20).focal_max(10).not()
```

My issue is with the `not()`. Both `swbdMask` and `hmask` are ee.Image objects. I tried using `not` but it changes the object type into boolean which is clearly not what I want.
Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: Reading the docs https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-not#javascript it says that either a 0 or 1 will be returned. Which from my understanding is basically the same as a boolean. I didnt use the package before so this is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time it states that the returned object is an Image. I think it does it pixel wise in this case, I guess. At least this is how I understood it